# Android LiveWallpaper with OpenGL Objects

Tags: android, image, rendering, opengl-es-2.0, live-wallpaper

I have searched alot about creating a live wallpaper using opengl.In that I can only able to find the drawing shapes and rendering it.But I want to assign the objects (images) for rendering?Can anyone help me or guide me?

Where I can find the sample code?

Thanks in prior!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using a framework is a better way to create your wallpaper.

I know that libGdx allows to make live wallpaper. Drawing shapes and images is supported.
Here a tutorial for wallpapers creation:
http://molotuspi.blogspot.fr/2013/09/how-to-make-simple-android-live.html

And here the website of libGdx:
http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/

Answer (score 0):

You will need this implementation of `WallpaperService` to create OpenGL ES live wallpapers: https://github.com/markfguerra/GLWallpaperService